# Phone Conversation with Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, twilio, twilio-api

I am currently trying to build a Python app allowing to ring my phone from my Raspberry Pi. This application should ideally allow to create a bidirectional and interactive conversation (as a standard phone call) between the user of the phone and the user of the raspberry, which is connected to a Jabra speaker.
I first followed the tutorial for outbound calls:

```
def make_call():
    account_sid = "ACXXX" 
    auth_token = "07XXX" 

    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
    call = client.calls.create( 
                            url="https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EHXXXX", 
                            to="+123456789", 
                            from_="+987654321"
                          )
```

The code above rings my phone, so I guess my Twilio account is correctly set up. However, when answering my phone, the phone call abruptly stops.
From the documentation, I also tried to change my TwiML instructions to :

> During an active call, you can use TwiML’s  verb to connect the current caller to another party.
> The following example shows the most basic use of :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>415-123-4567</Dial>
</Response>
```

> If the party at 415-123-4567 answers the call, the two parties can communicate until one hangs up.

This creates an new call to my phone, requiring me to end the first call to answer the second one, but still hangs up directly.
What could be the problem to my use-case ? Does Twilio natively handle the bidirectional conversations ? Is the solution more complex than that and requires me to extract audio from the Jabra and stream it to Twilio (and vice-versa) ?
Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: When the call abruptly stops, it usually means there was an error. Can you check the [error log](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/troubleshooting/debugging-tools) to see more details? Also, what is the TwiML response of your URL `https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EHXXXX`?

Comment: > Can you check the error log to see more details? 

I don't have any errors in the logs, and all the calls get the status "Completed". 

> Also, what is the TwiML response of your URL

The url returns 'AccountSid is missing in the request', which is weird as I created a TwiML Bin to say "Hello world" and I correctly hear it on my phone.

I also tried to replace the `url` parameter by `twiml='<Response><Say>Ahoy, World!</Say></Response>'`. But again, I hear the phrase correctly, then the phone call hangs up.

Comment: Ah, I see. So you hear the phrase but you are surprised it hangs up after that, is that right?

Comment: Yes. I would just like to call my phone from my Raspberry Pi, and allow both users to communicate by voice, exactly as a classic phone call.

Answer (score 0):

Your call is being disconnect because the TwiML instructions were completed successfully. If you want to avoid this, you can delay the disconnect event by using the [`<Pause />` tag](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/pause).

This will give you more tine to [Modify Calls In Progress With Python](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-modify-calls-in-progress/python) with new instructions:

```py
# Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install
import os
from twilio.rest import Client


# Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
# and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

call = client.calls('CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') \
             .update(twiml='<Response><Say>Ahoy there</Say></Response>')

print(call.to)
```

Comment: I would like my call to proceed until the person on the phone hangs up. I am not sure to understand how I can stream voice from the phone to the Raspberry speaker, and then from the Raspberry speaker to the phone, allowing both person to communicate. Does Twilio natively allow to do so ?

Comment: I have the feeling your question is much broader and more complex than what a single answer on this platform can provide. It sounds like you are trying to implement something like the [dev phone](https://github.com/twilio-labs/dev-phone). Maybe you can check out the source code of this project and reverse engineer it.

Comment: I found a project similar to what I am trying to accomplish: https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-python

which allows to:
- Create a call from the browser to a mobile phone
- Allow both users to speak and hear each other until one of them hangs up.

This project seems more complicated than mine, so I am surprised there are no easier way to do with Twilio API.

From there I would like to:
- Make a call from a Python script instead of a browser
- Handle the speaker and microphone. For some reason, this seems to be automatically handled in the QuickStart.